# Sqoop to import from db2

Tags: db2, sqoop

I am trying to import some tables from db2 through sqoop. I have placed the `db2jcc.jar` file and `db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar` files in /var/lib/sqoop/ directory. When I run the below sqoop import command

`sqoop import --driver com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver --connect jdbc:db2://192.168.1.1:3306/test --username user --password pass --table abc -- target-dir /user/w5`

I get an error:

> "Execution failed due to a distribution protocol error that caused deallocation of the conversation".

Please help me fix this.

Comment: Are you able to query over this  `abc` table using same `db2jcc.jar` and same credentials in JDBC client (_I mean without sqoop directly using jar_)?

Comment: Yes I could query the table. I just updated my query. Here's the updated query

sqoop import --driver com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver --connect jdbc:db2://192.168.1.1:50000/test --username user --password pass --table abc --split-by abc.id -- target-dir /user/w5 -m 1

And now I get the error as "An appropriate license file db2jcc_license_*.jar must be provided in the CLASSPATH setting"

Could you please let me know how and where I can set this